Create a new repo based on another repo branch with only the history of the branch
I want to extract a branch from its original repo and create new repo based on that branch, while keeping only the history of this branch.
A-----------------------------
 \     /  \    \     /
  B----    \    D----
            C-----------------

In the example above, I want to create a new repo based on the C branch, with all its history, like there has always been only the C branch:
C-----------------

I already tried git clone --branch C --depth 17 http://repolink.git, but the result is a shallow repo which is not usable like a classic repo.
Is it possible to achieve this without creating a new repo and redoing all the commits manually?
Edit :
Thanks for the replies, but when I execute these commands:
git clone --branch C --single-branch http://repolink.git
Or
git clone --branch C --depth 17 http://repolink.git
git fetch origin C --unshallow
The result is a repo that has only the C branch in it, but also all the history of other branches prior to the C branch creation, in the example above, all the history of the A branch:
----------C-----------------

What I want is to keep only the commits and history starting from the C branch creation:
C-----------------


Just run git clone --branch C http://repolink.git. That gets you a local repository with a single branch (and the entire history of that branch).

You can use git fetch origin C --unshallow to get the complete history of C. @larsks --single-branch is needed. --depth implies --single-branch. Without --depth, it should be explicitly specified.

A branch is just a name for one commit. The "history" is all the ancestors of that commit. Thus, cloning a single branch gets the right answer. It may not be what you want but it is correct — it clones the history of the branch. If you want something different then you might need to describe the problem in a different way. What you call "the history of the A branch", before the C branch was created, is part of the history of the C branch.

Ok, thanks @matt. Then, is it possible to remove every ancestor commits, from the repo initialization, to the commit where the C branch is created?

Just use the depth parameter as you were already told. Count backwards from the tip of branch C and see how many degrees of ancestry you want to keep. Do not say unshallow, that ruins the work you just did.
